# Increment string value in List

Tags: c#, list, windows-store-apps

This is not much complicated. But I am wondering how to make it possible.

```
XmlAttribute ids3 = item.GetAttributeNode("href");
string hrefname = ids3.Value;
value1.Add(hrefname); //Value1 is List
StorageFile hreffile = await strfolder.GetFileAsync(value1[0]);
string html = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(hreffile);
```

In the `value1` List I have more than one value. when I run my code usually it is giving the first value in the list. I want to load `hreffile` value in a order.
Simply,How to increment string value in List

Comment: I don't understand why you need a list here?

Comment: `value1[0]` always returns the value at the same index. What are you trying to achieve? iterate over the list using a `for`-loop? Using a `foreach` on the list?

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh 
I have many values to store,Then better to go with Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand what you want to do with the contents of all files. But since you have a list of values for input, the output should probably again be a list of values:

```
var htmls = new List<string>();
foreach(var value in value1)
{
    StorageFile hreffile = await strfolder.GetFileAsync(value);
    html.Add(await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(hreffile));
}
// htmls will now be a list of all file contents
```

Alternatively you could do the same using LINQ:

```
var htmls = value1.Select(v => 
    {
        StorageFile hreffile = await strfolder.GetFileAsync(value);
        return await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(hreffile);
    }).ToList();
```

In both cases you can now access individual file contents from `htmls` list.

Comment: Thanks for considering my question.
I have already a `list` `Value1` then what need of `htmls`. 
By using the file names in `list` I want to load in webview in order.

Comment: @kumar In order as in at the same time one below the other in the same `WebView`? Or one after the other having the user navigating between pages?

Comment: One after the other,when user taped to next when end of the the current html file, & I want to implement for load previous file when user comes to previous page form current.
For this I no need for For loop(am I right);

Answer (score 1):

try using a loop and loop through all values of Value1 list regardless of the number of values

```
// assuming your Value1 is List<string>
foreach(string value in Value1)
{
  StorageFile hreffile = await strfolder.GetFileAsync(value);
  string html = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(hreffile);
  // rest of your code needs to go in here
}
```

Comment: yes it is. what exactly are you trying to achieve? do you always need the 2nd value or what?

Comment: Sorry for late responding to the answer. 
Yes. I want to remaining values. whenever the operations complete with first value, I will go through next string value. 
Thanks..